# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, pipe

I'm trying to create a custom pipe in Angular 2. When I tried to run it, I got an error message:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'

Then I googled it and found out I should use `declarations: [ mypipe]` Instead of `pipes: [mypipe]`, but I got similar error again:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> 'declarations' does not exist in type 'Component'

Can anyone explain this, please?

**EDIT:**

I've just deleted the pipes/declarations line and it worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pipe not only in declarations but in export section of the module

```
exports: [ mypipe]
```

What it's saying there's no declaration section in the component.

Read [Pipes Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

> Note the following:
>
> - You use your custom pipe the same way you use built-in pipes.
> - You must include your pipe in the `declarations` array of the `AppModule`.
>
> Remember the declarations array
>
> You must manually register custom pipes. If you don't, Angular reports
>   an error. In the previous example, you didn't list the `DatePipe`
>   because all Angular built-in pipes are pre-registered.

Comment: can you pleeeease explain this to me?  I created the pipe with CLI, then  in the `export class...` I created custom  pipe-code. Then in the component I imported the pipe. ...that's it.

Comment: dudeeee... exactly! that's why I'm asking you to explain this... because when I did everything as it should be by the docs, I got an error. But when I removed it, it worked as it should...

Comment: No, it's not if you did it like that you weren't get the error. If you post a plunker I can look at it and say what's wrong with it.

Comment: lol, dude... why are you saying it's not while it is?! :D I'm running it atm without ANY error... and my custom pipe working. Perhpas angular2 updated it somehow, I can't say for sure, but this works just fine. Would be nice to know why, if anyone got this - please share